# Scala debugging

Tags: scala, debugging

I am new to Scala and I have setup an environment with IntelliJ. I found out one problem I could not explain, here is the code:

```
object HelloWorld extends App{
    print("before")
    var aMap = Map("A"->1, "B"->2)
    println("after")
    println(aMap)
}
```

I noticed that `println(aMap)` could clearly print out the `Map("A"->1, "B"->2)`, so I want to debug and found out if `Map` has implemented an `funcn` which will be called by `println`, using IntelliJ. So I set a debug point on:

```
println(aMap)
```

When I "step into" the function, it seems `var aMap = Map("A"->1, "B"->2)` was called again! So , whats the reason that this was called a second time?

Comment: How do you know the assignment is called again? Do you see it in your stack trace? Is the memory reference of aMap changed?

Comment: What happens if you change `var` to `val`?

Comment: @Jordan Parmer  Yes, I saw the call stack, when hit println(aMap) and press F7 to stepinto it, I could see on the top of call frames is the line of var aMap ..., In python, if you want to print an object, it will call the object __str__ method, and I thought scala may have such kind of features, well, it turned out that var aMap =..this line is hit again, I don't know the reason, jdk is 17u55 scala is 2.11.0

Comment: I changed to val, and seems val aMap = .. this line is hit again. I didn' mean that the assignment is called again, I just meant that using debug mode with step into, it seems that line was hit again, and I don't know the reason. Am I missing something?

Comment: it's still unclear what bothers you -- are you're stating that there is a variable aMap which is assigned twice, or what? if so, as Jordan said, you can check whether object reference (it looks like a hash) has changed -- this is evidence of abovementioned scenario, otherwise it's just a debugger wart, who is probably got confused with [DelayedInit semantics](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.App).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All top level fields (`var/val`) are also turned into methods to help with the concept of a [uniform access principle](http://docs.scala-lang.org/glossary/).

```
var map = Map(1->2)
val list = List(1,2)
```

becomes

```
var map = Map(1->2)
def map = map
def map_=(nValue: Map[Int.Int]) {map = nValue}

val list = List(1,2)
def list = list
// No setters for vals
```

So when you call `println(aMap)` it uses the hidden accessor method to get the value of aMap.

This is all happening because you are at the top-level of the object. Had this been in a method:

```
object HelloWorld extends App{
  def run() {
    print("before")
    var aMap = Map("A"->1, "B"->2)
    println("after")
    println(aMap)
  }
  run()
}
```

Then the `var aMap` would be a local variable and not use an indirect lookup.